# CKAN extensions not working if ckanext-sparql activated

Tags: sparql, ckan

I'm trying to install several extensions on CKAN. They all seem to work perfectly fine until I install ckanext-sparql.

I've followed the instructions on its website, and if I have the SPARQL extension working alone, it works great, but when I try to add another extension, it gives me back the following error message:

> ckan.plugins.core.PluginNotFoundException: sparql_interface

I have installed the extensions on the virtual environment and they all work *except* when I try to add SPARQL. The SPARQL extension works, but *only* if no other extension is activated.

Comment: But you added all installed CKAN extensions in your configuration file (e.g. `development.ini`) on the `ckan.plugins` line? And you installed all with `python setup.py develop`? What are the other extensions that you try to run?

Comment: Yes, I have added them to my configuration file and installed them with python setup.py develop. I have installed extensions such as ckanext-harvest, ckanext-googleanalytics, ckanext-spatial and ckanext-disqus. I have also installed ckanext-sparql, which is the one that's giving problems.

Comment: I just successfully installed ckanext-sparql on one of my CKAN instances (together with other extensions). There must be an error in your configuration. Are there any other errors in the logfile?

Comment: @JavierHuerta Could you answer your own question (as an answer, not a comment) and then accept you answer as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved the problem. It turns out that the ckanext-sparql extension wasn't registering itself correctly. I've added it manually to the easy-install.pth file where all the other extensons were, and now everything works fine.